# Python/MySQL - Rename CSV file

Tags: python, mysql, csv, tkinter

I created a small application to export data from my mysql database in csv, it works, but if I want to create another report is presented the following error:

pymysql.err.InternalError: (1086, "File '/TEMP/.CSV' already exists")

Yes, the file already exists. My question is, how do I generate two reports, even with the same name. Ex. **hi.csv**, and following **hi.csv (1)**
Following is the code below:

```
import tkinter as tk
import pymysql


root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("")
root.title("excel teste")

conn = pymysql.connect(host="localhost", port=3306, user="root", password="", database="omnia")
with conn:
    print("connect successfull!")
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    with cursor:
        cursor.execute("SELECT VERSION()")
        versao = cursor.fetchone()
        print("Versão do gerenciador Maria DB: %s" % versao)


def exp_rel_con_pag():
    conn = pymysql.connect(host="localhost", port=3306, user="root", password="", database="omnia")
    with conn:
        statm = "SELECT * FROM omniacademp INTO OUTFILE '/TEMP/"".CSV' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY ''"
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        with cursor:
            cursor.execute(statm)
            results = cursor.fetchone()
            print(results)


tk.Button(root, width=15, text="run", command=exp_rel_con_pag).place(x=10, y=10)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: the `OUTFILE` will have to be dynamically created, does that make sense?

Comment: how about using `try-except` and a counter, using the counter value in the filename, increasing the counter every time that exception is raised?

Comment: @DeepSpace better practice would be using the `os` module to check if the file exists as opposed to `try/except`

Comment: @aws_apprentice then OP will need to start from 0 every time, and check if the file exists until they find a name that does not exist. My idea is the other way around. In any case the idea is the same. Also, EAFP concept prefers the `try-except` approach (ignoring the small overhead it adds). It is also less prone to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-of-check_to_time-of-use

Comment: @aws_apprentice actually, as soon as a race condition is possible, a try/except IS the "best practice" - a file by the same name could very well be created by another process between the os.path.exists check and the cursor.execute call.

Comment: where is the race condition here?

Comment: Personally I typically add a timestamp to my file names.

Answer (score 0):

You could import the error class:

```
from pymysql.err import InternalError
```

Add a counter:

```
fileIndex = 0
```

Then see if the file already exists:

```
try:
  statm = "SELECT * FROM omniacademp INTO OUTFILE '/TEMP/HI.CSV' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY ''"
  cursor.execute(statm)
except InternalError:
  statm = "SELECT * FROM omniacademp INTO OUTFILE '/TEMP/HI ({}).CSV' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY ''".format(fileIndex)
  cursor.execute(statm)
  fileIndex += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add some level of dynamic naming. Personally I use timestamps.

For example I use `openpyxl` to write my excel files and `datetime` for my timestamp.

By using a timestamp down to seconds There is very little chance you will ever have a problem with the filename.

Here is the code I use once I have data to write.

```
import os
import openpyxl
from datetime import datetime as dt


list_of_data = [['row1'], ['row2'], ['row3'], ['row4']]

wb = openpyxl.Workbook()  # create workbook
main_ws = wb.worksheets[0]  # designate what worksheet I am working on.
for sub_list in list_of_data:
    main_ws.append(sub_list)  # writing data to each row.

# creating timestamp while removing special characters.
time_stamp = ''.join([{'-': '', ' ': '', ':': '', '.': ''}.get(c, c) for c in str(dt.now())])[0:12]
# build file name.
file_name = '{} - {}.xlsx'.format('report', time_stamp)
# using os library to build path to my local documents folder.
path = os.path.join(os.environ['USERPROFILE'], 'Documents', file_name)
# saving wb.
wb.save(filename=path)
```

As you can see I now have an excel file in my docs folder with a timestamp.
[image]